# Find the radius of convergence, $a_n=f^{n}(0)/n!$ and $f(z)=z+f(z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f$ be an analytic function such that $$f(z)=z+f(z^2)$$

Let $a_n=f^{n}(0)/n!$

Then find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}z^{n}$

$f'(z)=1+f'(z^2)2z$ so $a_1=1$

$f''(z)=f'(z^2)2+f''(z^2)4z^2$ so $a_2=2/2!$

But this process become lengthy as we go to higher derivatives. Is there a more cleaver and interesting way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1553123, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2389160, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2441464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing coefficients we get $a_n=a_{2n}, n \geq 1$ and $a_1=1$. Hence $a_{2^{n}}=1$ for all $n$ and $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd, $n \neq 1$. . The radius of convergence $R$is given by $\frac 1 R=\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$ and hence $R=1$.

Comment: Doesn't it show that $R\geq 1$?

Comment: How do we get that $a_n=a_{2^{n}}$ Thanks

Comment: $\sum a_nz^{n}=f(z)=z+f(z^{2})=z+\sum a_n z^{2n}$. The coefficient of $z^{2n}$ on LHS is $a_n$ and it is $a_{2n}$ on RHS.

Comment: This answer needs more details. $a_k = 0$ when $k>1$ is odd. So $a_n = 0$ if it's not a power of $2$.

Comment: @Jakobian I missed a sup while typing I meant to write $\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$.